# How can i get the Watch window vs 2005 while running SSIS

Tags: ssis

Hi I am not able to get my watch window while running ssis package ,please can help 
Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you found it by now, but you can get it by going to Debug on the menu, then Windows, then Watch, then select Watch 1. Shortcut is Ctrl+Alt+W, 1